# Regex for HTML RESPONSE BODY present under div tag

Tags: regex, html-parsing, gatling

I need to build a regex for extracting the value present under value field.
i.e   "f70a8c3d0a6cbe2e235c7fd1dd27d052df7412ea"

HTML RESPONSE BODY :
Note: I have pasted just a minor part of the response....but formToken key is unique

```
<div class="hidden">
    <input name="formToken    type="hidden"
            value="f70a8c3d0a6cbe2e235c7fd1dd27d052df7412ea"    
    />
</div>
```

I wrote the below regex but it returned nothing:

```
regex("formToken" type="hidden" value="([^"]*)"/>).find(0).exists, found nothing
```

Comment: Did you try `regex("""value="([^"]*)"""")`? I mean, you might need to use  triple quotation marks.

Comment: Thanks for replying Stribizhev...but the above reponse was just a part of HTML Body
It also has more than 50 Values...example
    <input type="hidden" title="tzdetect.pref.tzid" value="Etc/GMT" />
    <input type="hidden" title="tzdetect.pref.tzname" value="(GMT+00:00) GMT" />
    <input type="hidden" title="tzdetect.pref.janOffset" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" title="tzdetect.pref.julyOffset" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" title="tzdetect.pref.nothanks" value="-28800000,-25200000" />................

Comment: [Dont parse (X)html with a regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
regex("type="hidden".*value="(.*?)[ \t]*"/>).find(0).exists
```

Comment: Thanks Pogo, but as I said earlier we were having more than 1 match for the above regex and our only unique key is formToken, so I think we need to build on that line.

Comment: It would be easier if you give me your full input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a regex, you could use a [css selector check](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.4/http/http_check.html#http-check-css) which is probably way easier once you have ids or css classes to search for.

Comment: Thanks Stephane

.check(css("input[name='formToken']", "value").saveAs("formTokex"))

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all....I was able to get formToken using css

.check(css("input[name='formToken']", "value").saveAs("formTokex"))

Answer (score 0):

Works like this for me:

```
.exec(http("request_1")
        .get("<<<<YOUR_URL>>>>>")
        .check(css("form[name='signInForm']", "action").saveAs("urlPath"))
```

and later printing it:

```
println(session( "urlPath" ).as[String])
```